# Ring Buffer using templates/macros

Tags: circular-list, nim

I just wrote my [first Nim module](https://github.com/megawac/RingBuffer.nim) and was hoping someone with some experience with Nim or similar languages could take a look. In particular I was hoping someone could speak if the use of `template` is idiomatic (or if they'd be better as a `proc`) as I have no experience using them in any other programming language.

I was also curious if it'd be a good idea to macro the two `add` implementations to reduce the amount of redundant code

```
import macros

type
  RingBuffer*[T] = object
    ## A ring buffer is a sequence-like type which can store
    ## up to `length` elements. After `length` elements are
    ## added to the buffer, new items will begin to replace
    ## the oldest ones (i.e. the elements at the start of the
    ## buffer).
    data: seq[T]
    # indicates where elements should be positioned in data
    head, tail: int
    size, length*: int

template adjustHead(b: expr): stmt =  
  b.head = (b.length + b.tail - b.size + 1) mod b.length;

template adjustTail(b, change: expr): stmt =  
  b.tail = (b.tail + change) mod b.length

proc newRingBuffer*[T](length: int): RingBuffer[T] =
  ## Construct a new Ringbuffer which can hold up to `length` elements
  let s = newSeq[T](length)
  RingBuffer[T](data: s, head: 0, tail: -1, size: 0, length: length)

proc `[]`*[T](b: RingBuffer[T], idx: int): T {.inline} =
  ## Get an item at index (adjusted)
  b.data[(idx + b.head) mod b.length]

proc `[]=`*[T](b: var RingBuffer[T], idx: int, item: T) {.raises: [IndexError].} =
  ## Set an item at index (adjusted)
  if idx == b.size: inc(b.size)
  elif idx > b.size: raise newException(IndexError, "Index " & $idx & " out of bound")

  b.data[(idx + b.head) mod b.length] = item

proc len*(b: RingBuffer): int = b.size

proc add*[T](b: var RingBuffer[T], item: T) =
  ## Add an element to the buffer 
  adjustTail(b, 1)
  b.data[b.tail] = item
  b.size = min(b.size + 1, b.length)
  adjustHead(b)

proc add*[T](b: var RingBuffer[T], data: openArray[T]) =
  ## Add elements to the buffer 
  for item in data:
    adjustTail(b, 1)
    b.data[b.tail] = item
  b.size = min(b.size + len(data), b.length)
  adjustHead(b)

proc pop*[T](b: var RingBuffer[T]): T =
  ## Remove an element from the buffer and return it
  result = b.data[b.tail] # Note: will throw error if oob
  adjustTail(b, -1)
  b.size -= 1
  adjustHead(b)

iterator `items`*[T](b: RingBuffer[T]): T =
  for i in 0..b.size - 1:
    yield b[i]

iterator `pairs`*[T](b: RingBuffer[T]): tuple[a: int, b: T] =
  for i in 0..b.size - 1:
    yield (i, b[i])

proc `@`*[T](b: RingBuffer[T]): seq[T] =
  ## Convert the buffer to a sequence
  var s = newSeq[T](b.size)
  for i, item in b:
    s[i] = item
  result = s

converter toSeq*[T](b: RingBuffer[T]): seq[T] = @b
```